# Angular $http post with custom headers

Tags: angularjs, post, header, command

I am new to angular and am from .net framework. I need to post a angular request to .net service, where it expects two custom headers from the client.
angular post command:
var request = $http(

```
        {
            url: "http://localhost:53585/api/myService/Validate",
            method: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(payload),
            headers: {  'first_token': sessionService.first_token, 'second_token': sessionService.second_token } 

            });
```

But in the service side, I can see only first_token in the request header and not the second token.  What I am missing here?

Comment: make sure sessionService.second_token is not undefined?

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with my service. I figured out and restarted the IIS and then service was able to read both the headers token

Answer (score 0):

I found this method in a forum, it works.

```
return this.http.post<any>('https://yourendpoint', { username, password }, { headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorizaion', 'your token')})
      .pipe(map(user => {
        // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
        if (user && user.token) {
          // sto`enter code here`re user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
          localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
        }
        console.log(user);
        return user;
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: As I would rather abstract the code for the header({ headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorizaion', 'your token')}) there is possibly a unresolved bug that prevents this from happening. I submitted a bug ticket. Also this is coming out of an Angular 6 project so syntax will differ.